# Is the following error of much important and if it is, how can I repair it?

Tags: android, eclipse

When I am clicking the "Finish" button during the creation of Android Application Project, the console is showing the following lines in red:

```
 [2016-06-05 11:27:14 - HelloWorld] D:\Desktop 16.05.16\Car Race 3D\gaming
\HelloWorld\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for     item: No resource found that matches the given name                      
'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
 [2016-06-05 11:27:14 - HelloWorld] 
[2016-06-05 11:27:14 - HelloWorld] D:\Desktop 16.05.16\Car Race 3D\gaming    \HelloWorld\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving     parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name     'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-06-05 11:27:14 - HelloWorld] 
[2016-06-05 11:27:14 - HelloWorld] D:\Desktop 16.05.16\Car Race 3D\gaming    \HelloWorld\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving     parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name     'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2016-06-05 11:27:14 - HelloWorld] 
[2016-06-05 11:27:17 - HelloWorld] D:\Desktop 16.05.16\Car Race 3D\gaming    \HelloWorld\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving       parent for item: No resource found that matches the given      name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-06-05 11:27:17 - HelloWorld] 
[2016-06-05 11:27:17 - HelloWorld] D:\Desktop 16.05.16\Car Race 3D\gaming    \HelloWorld\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving     parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name     'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-06-05 11:27:17 - HelloWorld] 
[2016-06-05 11:27:17 - HelloWorld] D:\Desktop 16.05.16\Car Race 3D\gaming    \HelloWorld\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving     parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name     'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2016-06-05 11:27:17 - HelloWorld] 
[2016-06-05 11:31:18 - HelloWorld] D:\Desktop 16.05.16\Car Race 3D\gaming    \HelloWorld\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving        parent for item: No resource found that matches the given     name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-06-05 11:31:18 - HelloWorld] 
[2016-06-05 11:31:18 - HelloWorld] D:\Desktop 16.05.16\Car Race 3D\gaming    \HelloWorld\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving     parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name     'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-06-05 11:31:18 - HelloWorld] 
[2016-06-05 11:31:18 - HelloWorld] D:\Desktop 16.05.16\Car Race 3D\gaming    \HelloWorld\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving     parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name     'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
 [2016-06-05 11:31:18 - HelloWorld] 
 [2016-06-05 11:33:35 - HelloWorld] D:\Desktop 16.05.16\Car Race 3D\gaming    \HelloWorld\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving         parent for item: No resource found that matches the given     name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-06-05 11:33:35 - HelloWorld] 
[2016-06-05 11:33:35 - HelloWorld] D:\Desktop 16.05.16\Car Race 3D\gaming    \HelloWorld\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving     parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name     'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-06-05 11:33:35 - HelloWorld] 
[2016-06-05 11:33:35 - HelloWorld] D:\Desktop 16.05.16\Car Race 3D\gaming    \HelloWorld\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving     parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name     'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
 [2016-06-05 11:33:35 - HelloWorld]
```

I am using the Eclipse IDE. Is this problem serious? If it is, then how can I repair it? I configured the Eclipse by following the following site:
http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Setup-Eclipse-for-Android-App-Development/

Comment: You should search this online, its been talked about in many posts. It looks like you haven't imported the app compat library. you should go to project properties and add this library to your project.

Comment: I have searched everywhere, and seen videos that show how to create an Android Application Project correctly in Youtube, with no result.

Comment: Have you imported the appcompat library on your project ?

Comment: Try to change the parent of AppBaseTheme of your styles file to `android:style/Theme.Holo.Light` for al your values folder.

Comment: I am a beginner in Android. Could you please inform me how to import appcompat library in my project and how to change the parent of AppBaseTheme?